# How to draw a fancy box with an overlay rectangle enclosing the title box

Tags: tcolorbox, tikz-styles, mdframed, bclogo

I kindly request to be helped to achieve my target of recreating the fancy box below.

[image]

I attempted with the codes below:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mybrown}{HTML}{B35823}
\definecolor{myorange}{HTML}{ED8C2B}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{myex}[2][]{enhanced,  
 colframe=white,colback=white,colbacktitle=yellow,breakable,
 fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black,right=1mm,
 overlay={\draw[gray,rounded corners](0.32,78pt)--(340pt,78pt)--(340pt,55pt)--(0.32,55pt)--cycle;
 \draw[gray,rounded corners](340pt,66.5pt)--(350pt,66.5pt)--(350pt,-50pt);
 },
 attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.3cm,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
 boxed title style={enhanced,arc=0pt,outer arc=5pt,colframe=mybrown,interior code={ 
 \node[anchor=west,fill=myorange,minimum height=0.4cm,inner ysep=0pt,rounded corners=3pt](a) at ([xshift=-8pt]interior.east){\color{white}\thetcbcounter}; 
 }  
 },
 title={\color{white}Example},#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{myex}{}
You are provided with substance Q which contains two cations and two anions. Carry out the following tests on Q and identify the cations and anions in it. Identify any gas(es) evolved. Record your results in the table below.
\end{myex}
\end{document}
```

And it gave me the image below which is far away from what I need.

[image]